Knockout dropdown with multiple selection option does not populate observable array
I have an application which places a dropdown menu on a page.  The dropdown is defined with this code:
<select id="cmbVillages" multiple="multiple" class="uk-select" data-bind="options: VillagesList, selectedOptions: selectedVillages, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Code'"></select>

The dropdown gets populated with this code:
if (vm.VillagesList.length > 0) {
    vm.Village = vm.VillagesList[0].Code; // Set the initial Locale value
} else {
    vm.Village = '';
}
$('#cmbVillages').igCombo({
    dataSource: vm.VillagesList,
    textKey: 'Name',
    valueKey: 'Code',
    enableClearButton: false,
    width: '220px',
    height: '27px',
    initialSelectedItems: [{ value: vm.VillagesList[0].Code }],
    selectionChanged: function (evt, ui) {
        if (ui.items[0]?.data?.Code) {
            vm.Village = ui.items[0].data.Code;
        }
    }
});

The dropdown gets populated correctly and I am able to select multiple menu items.
I assume the variable vm.selectedOptions will be populated with the items that are selected by the user from the dropdown.
I introduced this code to see the data that is being stored in vm.selectedOptions:
vm.selectedVillages = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.selectedVillages.subscribe(function (newValues) {
    console.log("Selected Villages: ", newValues);
});

when I run the code, even though I am selecting multiple items in the dropdown, nothing is ever written to the console.
Do I have this wired up correctly or am I missing something which is preventing the values selected by the user to be added/removed from the vm.selectedVillages array?
Thank you.

I haven't used knockout in a very long time so I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't update in this case, but as an alternative couldn't you update the array in the selectionChanged callback? It's not as ideal as having the observable update automatically but it could be a workaround.

It looks like you are close.  When using knockoutjs you need to use observable and observableArray if you want the screen to react changes to the underlying object.
I hope the following example helps.


var villages = [{
  Code: "1",
  Name: "Village 1"
}, {
  Code: "2",
  Name: "Village 2"
}, {
  Code: "3",
  Name: "Village 3"
}];

var selectedTowns = [
   "2","3"
];

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.VillagesList = ko.observableArray(villages);
  self.selectedVillages = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedVillages.subscribe(function(newValues) {
    console.log("Selected Villages: ", newValues);
  });
  self.addVillage = function(){
    var villageCount = self.VillagesList().length + 1;
    var newVillage = {
      Code: `${villageCount}`,
      Name: `Village ${villageCount}`
    }
    self.VillagesList.push(newVillage);
    
    console.log("New Village added", newVillage);
  };
  
  self.setSelectedVillages = function(){
    self.selectedVillages(selectedTowns);
  }
}
var viewModel = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.setSelectedVillages();
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<select id="cmbVillages" multiple="multiple" class="uk-select form-select" data-bind="options: VillagesList, selectedOptions: selectedVillages, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Code'"></select>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addVillage">Add Village</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: setSelectedVillages">Set selected villages</button>



